# How would I build a master magic item crafter/blacksmith type character?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization

So I had this idea for a character who is basically obsessed with magic items, making, collecting, using, having, any and every magic item he can get his hands on: effectively a batman type character.

I was thinking something along the lines of a Dwarf Wizard. That way he's already a good craftsman and gets access to the magic item creation feats, but I'm not sure exactly how to build it with good prestige classes or other features to take in order to get everything I want.

I want a character who has a magic item for every possible situation that he would encounter. I want random magic items that don't have any useful function, (i.e. jewelry that can be made to rattle or stay quiet, A belt that will wind itself around your waist, etc.) What's the best build for this character?

Comment: Did you discover Artificer as being your accepted answer yet?

Answer (score 19):

Artificer!  It's a class based around making and using magic items.  It's exactly what you're looking for and a powerful class to boot.

Instead of spells, you get a short list of "infusions" (spells) that boost your magic items.

But the best part is an allowance of free XP to be used on magic items at each level. You get all of basic item creation feats (Scrible scroll, brew potion, craft wondrous item, craft magic arms and armor craft rod, craft staff, forge ring) as bonus feats. At 5th level you can reclaim experience points used to create item from already existing one and use them to create a new one. It starts pretty thin (you can make a few scrolls and potions at early levels) but by level ten you can have several wands or magic items kicking around.  With some cheesy feat stacking you can cast multiple charges out of your wand (scorching ray is best) and be looking at 40d6 of damage by mid levels.

The class is found in the Eberron Campaign Setting.

Comment: that sounds perfect, is it a base class or do you have to prestige into it?

Comment: @Edd: It's a base class, but it's Eberron specific, so you may have to ask your DM for permission first if you're playing any other setting. Most DMs don't have any problem, though.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the answer. Otherwise the crafting system is too broken to be used more than only occasionally. And if homebrew is permitted, you may want to look at [this](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=71705) for a PrC.

Comment: Ahh, This is going to be so fun. I did some research into the stuff and convinced my DM to let me play a warforged artificer :D my character was so obsessed with magic items that he became one

Comment: @Edd Could you mark this answer as Accepted then? It will let other users browsing questions know that this one has been solved. :)

Comment: Last I checked, Artificier is presented as a prestige class in the DMG, I think it was.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially most of the "useless" ones would be related to imbuing Prestidigitation or other level 0 stuff.  Ultimately you want to max the craft skills and INT, take a spell casing class and focus feats on metamagic [creation]

Also, I'm assuming this is an arcane caster?

Comment: yeah, that was my idea, which is why i like wizard alot.

Answer (score 1):

A warlock.

He needs to be level 12+ before he can craft most stuff unless it merely requires caster level (though you can use scrolls as well), but after that, he can make literally any magical, non-artifact, item he wants that you have a crafting feat for, it just requires UMI checks, which he can as a class feature take 10 on to remove variance. If you have a really high charisma and/or Skill focus UMI the instant you hit lvl 12 you cannot fail when making any item requiring unmodified Arcane spells as your take 10 + skill (assuming you've been keeping it maxed out) is higher then a 9th level spell DC. And by 15 you can't fail at any divine spells. If you happen to have any meta-magic feats (which are normally useless to a warlock) you could use them to exceed the 9th lvl limit to make something as high as you can manage a check for. I.E. scribing a scroll of Charm person and heightening the spell to 20th spell level (the maximum you can raise a spell level) which ups the innate spell DC from 11 to 30. That check would require DC 35  to make in that case.

In addition he nothing but at will powers of which have several nice effects to choose from (24 flight is one of the biggest, at will invisibility, dimension doors as some examples) his attacks are either merged replicas of other mage spells, or modifications to his eldritch blast. He's a bit limited on choices per invocation level, but you can cover his weaknesses with scrolls, wands, staves, or other items that generate magical effects.

Comment: This answer is hard to read. If there was less text spent on how to optimise a warlock and more text spent on *why* these things you're describing accomplish the Questioner's goals, it might be more readable / a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a character solely for item creation, Dwarf Artificer/Battlesmith would work OK in theory – but I've never actually played that combination before.

If you want some combat flexibility, a Wizard or Sorcerer with the Battlesmith prestige class would work.

If you don't want to play a dwarf or prestige class, multiclass Wizard or Sorcerer with Artificer.

It all depends on what you want because there is a million-and-one ways to go. Personally I don't like to put all my eggs into one basket, and loathe wizards' need for spellbooks, so I would go Sorcerer/Artificer.

Comment: Are any of those classes better than others? Try to give us a single best answer (clearly artificer here). Beyond that, good answer.